# jquery ajax calling a method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using a class to do some CRUD stuff on a database, this one (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/real-world-oop-with-php-and-mysql) I am going to use jquery to check the if the username has been registered already.

I could just create a php file specifically for that task, but would just like to extend the class and create a method callled checkname().

How can I call this in jquery?

Comment: why don't you just do a query to check if the username is already in the db? if not -> create etc.

Comment: I sometimes like net tuts+ but that tutorial is frightening.

Comment: the information i needed was that it cannot be called directly. I can pass some data and use an if or switch statement to call it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to make ajax call to a php file following:

**PHP**  **[suppose, test.php]**

```
<?php

class ABC extends XYZ {
  public function checkname() {
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
      echo json_encode(array('status' => 'done'));
    }
  }
}
$ins = new ABC();
$ins->checkname(); // calling the function checkname

?>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'test.php', //  write the url correctly
  type: 'post',
  data: "name=XYZ&location=PQR"
}).done(function(response) {
   console.log(response.status); // will log done
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
   console.log("Failed: " + textStatus);
});
```

It is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use jQuery's Ajax functionality to access a PHP page that calls that function. You can't directly call a PHP function via Ajax, something on the backend has to be set up.